# solr extractingrequesthandler is not a org.apache.solr.request.SolrRequestHandler

Tags: solr, extract, solr-cell

I'm trying to use post.jar to index a folder with pdf files. i have added the requesthandler but i'm getting a error on startup.

To be it seems, that it could be a version conflict or a duplicate class load and is therefor not recognized as a SolrRequestHandler. Just a idea.

I'm running it solr 3.4 on a windows 2008 r2 server with iis.

CONFIG:

```
<lib dir="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jetty\solr\contrib\extraction\lib" />
<lib dir="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jetty\solr\dist\" regex="apache-solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jetty\solr\dist\" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />


<requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" multipartUploadLimitInKB="15000000" />
</requestDispatcher>
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" class="org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="fmap.Last-Modified">last_modified</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
    <!-- Optional. Specify one or more date formats to parse.  See DateUtil.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMATS for default date formats -->
    <lst name="date.formats">
      <str>dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

LOG:

```
    INFO: created /dataimport: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
Mai 30, 2013 3:20:43 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating Request Handler, org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler is not a org.apache.solr.request.SolrRequestHandler
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:425)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:459)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:157)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:563)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)

Mai 30, 2013 3:20:43 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher <init>
INFO: Opening Searcher@74eb711e main
Mai 30, 2013 3:20:43 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2$CommitTracker <init>
INFO: AutoCommit: if 10000 uncommited docs
```

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks like library conflict. Do you have two versions of Solr on the system? I would start by changing relative paths in  directives to absolute ones and see what happens. Perhaps your 'home' directory is not what you think it is. Or LaunchAnywhere does strange things with class path.

Comment: i changed the library paths (see above) but still get the same error. are there any other path i forgot besides the 3 i changed?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you class definition is not quite right. Can you double check it against Solr 3.4 example [solrconfig.xml](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_3_4/solr/example/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml) . It has the class name as *class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler"* . This uses a shortcut form of class reference, but it is probably better that way anyway.

Comment: i've gotten quite a bit farther but now i'm getting this after it sais that it is posting file

SimplePostTool: FATAL: Unexpected IOException java.io.FileNotFoundException: . (Access is denied)

when i'm trying to add docs with post.jar with the following command:  java -Dauto -Drecursive -Durl=http://localhost:8985/solr/tkb/update/extract -jar C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jetty\exampledocs\post.jar C:\web\development\tkb\internet\public\download

Comment: Make it a separate question, as the issue is separate.